# How to filter only those records which contains required string in DataFrame by ignoring characters in between

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge excel which I have imported using pandas. I would like to know how to filter records which has strings 'ABCD'

I need to filter only those records which has 'ABCD' by neglecting all the characters in between.
Say I have dataframe like this. Col_2 is the column which has 'ABCD'

```
col_1 col_2  col_3  col_4
 1    ABCD    123    890
 2    AB/CD   345    789
 3    XYZ     777    980
 4    AB_CD   010    345
```

The new dataframe should be

```
col_1 col_2  col_3  col_4
 1    ABCD    123    890
 2    AB/CD   345    789
 3    AB_CD   010    345
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `loc` and `str.replace`:

```
print(df.loc[df['col_2'].str.replace('[^ABCD]', '').eq('ABCD')])
```

Output:

```
   col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4
0      1   ABCD    123    890
1      2  AB/CD    345    789
3      4  AB_CD     10    345
```